# Zoom in Highmaps based on Lat/Long

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I have created a Bubble Highmap using various Lat/ Long and it is working fine. And i used proj4.js to make it work.

This is my series data:

```
var mapFinalData = [{
                name: 'Countries',
                mapData: mapData,
                color: "#F5F5F5",
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                showInLegend: false,
                nullColor: "#D6D8CB"
            }];
        mapFinalData.push({
                type: 'mapbubble',
                mapData: mapData,
                name: queryGenerator("topic-analysis", "getRawParams").topic,
                data: mapFData,
                joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
                minSize: 8,
                maxSize: 35,
                color: '#028E85',
                tooltip: {
                    backgroundColor:"#444444"
                }
            });
```

And i am able to plot map successfully.

But i need to zoom in into the map on a click of button to a specific lat/long.

I know i can zoom to a particular region with its code using

`$('#container').highcharts().get('EC').zoomTo();`

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Chart.mapZoom()` method? See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#Chart.mapZoom). You can get `centerX` and `centerY` from `Chart.fromLatLonToPoint()` method, again: [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#Chart.fromLatLonToPoint).